# interpret a sum geometrically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this sum: $1+3+5+...+(2n+1)$, where $n$ is a natural number.
I have to calculate it and interpret geometrically.
Well, it's easy to find out that it equals $(n+1)^2$.
But how to interpret it geometrically?
I don't think it's about a graph(parabola).
could you please give me at least an idea?

Comment: That question doesn't address the geometric interpretation, though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: the sum of odd numbers is a square quilt]

(Source: [Wooly Thoughts afghans](http://www.woollythoughts.com/afghans/rainbow.html))

Or, more generally, try [a search for "the sum of odd numbers is a square"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sum+of+odd+numbers+is+a+square&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You look for a square, also geometrically, with side $n+1$.

Slice it up for smaller squares, start with a unit square in a corner.

Answer (score 1):

Since this sum (n+1)^2 is the area of a square with side (n+1), draw a diagram of the n=1,2,3, ... squares with their lower left corner on the origin.

Enjoy!

Comment: There is also a nice configuration as a spiral from the centre